# how to return line of found string?

Tags: python

i need to find string in txt file, and return line, where it have been found.

if i want to search for '123' in txt file below, it should return third line, which contains '123:321'

txt file:
789:987
456:654
123:321

```
def search(txtfile, stringtosearch):
    with open(txtfile, 'r') as obj:
         if stringtosearch in obj:
             return linewherefound #There it should return line, where stringtosearch was found.
         else:
             return 'Not Found'
```

Comment: The _line_ or the line _number_?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the lines like such, and then return the line:

```
def search(txtfile, stringtosearch):
    with open(txtfile, 'r') as obj:
        for line in obj: # Iterate over lines in open file
            if stringtosearch in line:
                return line
        return 'Not Found'
```

Comment: that's what i don't want to do. i need for it to scan whole file at a time, not by lines.

Comment: There's no way to not go over the lines, and still know which line contains a string.

Comment: @crypt ??? then please update your question, e.g. give a sample input on which this code will not result in desired output

Comment: ok, thank you. but i have hundreeds of files with millions lines in them and searching by line makes it very slow. i wonder if i can use threading somehow.

Comment: @crypt yes, this is another reason for line-by-line evaluation. If you find the line "soon", you are finished, without dealing with the rest of the file

Comment: @JanStránský well yes, but it still needs to search trough millions of millins of lines, before it can find my string

Comment: @crypt yes, but "searching trough millions of millons of lines" is an intrinsic part of the task, I am afraid.. Depending on your specific data, there *may* be some better strategy, but in general I think you cannot much improve it..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually iterate over the lines while keeping track of line numbers:

```
def search(txtfile, stringtosearch):
    with open(txtfile, 'r') as obj:
        for linewherefound, line in enumerate(obj):
            if stringtosearch in line:
                return linewherefound
   
   return 'Not Found'
```

Note that `stringtosearch in obj` in your code will search for a line that's exactly *equal* to `stringtosearch`, not a line that *contains* it.

Comment: `if stringtosearch == line:` this does not fulfil the OP requirement

Comment: yes, the *exactly equal* is the problem. Citing OP: "i want to search for '123' in txt file below, it should return third line, which contains '123:321'"

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using the `enumerate()` function and the `readlines()` function. We will iterate in the `data` variable and when the string is found, the number of the line will be returned. If there is no match, it will return `Not Found`

```
def search(file, string):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    for j, i in enumerate(data):
        if string in i:
            return j
    return 'Not Found'
```

Comment: `data = f.readlines()` is not necessary here, just loop the file line by line and return in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file as a string, and count the number of newlines to the position in the file:

```
def search(txtfile, stringtosearch):
    with open(txtfile, 'r') as obj:
        data = obj.read()
    pos = data.find(stringtosearch)
    if pos != -1:
        return 1 + data.count('\n', 0, pos)
    else:
        return 'Not Found'

print(search("bar.txt", "lkjl"))
print(search("bar.txt", "123:321"))
print(search("bar.txt", "456:654"))
print(search("bar.txt", "789:987"))
```